# ios6 - how to make toolbar button perform action in another view controller

Tags: uitableview, ios6, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UI Toolbar with an Add BarButton. I want this to trigger an action in a subordinate viewController. I am stuck.

The toolbar is set up like this:

TopViewController.h

```
IBOutlet UIToolbar* toolbar;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *homeButton;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *addButton;

- (IBAction)homePlease:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addStuff:(id)sender;
```

TopViewController.m

```
@class ItemViewController;
#import "ItemViewController.h"

- (IBAction)homePlease:(id)sender {
    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)addStuff:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [self.itemViewController insertNewObject:self]; <-----
}
```

ItemViewController:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    AddItemViewController *addItem = [[AddItemViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddItem-iPad" bundle:nil];


    // Create a new managed object context for the new item - set its persistent store coordinator
    // to the same as that from the fetched results controller's context.

    NSManagedObjectContext .......

    [self.addContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];

    addItem.item = (DDItem *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addItem];
    nc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The Home button works fine.

The addButton fires (I see the log). But nothing else happens. The Add button is wired to the IBAction.

Any advice will be most welcome

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476361/adding-items-to-uitoolbar-programatically-not-working?rq=1) is correct. You must set the buttons within their presenting view controllers. I hope this helps others.